# How to add an element into a specific position of a list, using Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

This is the code I have so far. I believe that I'm close, but what returns is just #procedure, acknowledging that a procedure has created, it does not return the list with the newly added element. I have  been working on this for hours and I am at a loss of where I have gone wrong.

```
(define (add-into new p lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         (cons new lst)
        ((eq? p 0)
         (cons new lst)
        (else 
         (cons (car lst) (add-into (- p 1) new (cdr l))))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have parentheses problems, in one place you passed `l` instead of `lst` and the order of the parameters is incorrect when doing the recursive call. This should fix the errors:

```
(define (add-into new p lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         (cons new lst))
        ((= p 0)
         (cons new lst))
        (else 
         (cons (car lst) (add-into new (- p 1) (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: I am SO thankful for your help, I have been switching everything over so many times that I really started messing up my code. I am new at Scheme and the brackets are what always end up screwing me over. Thank you for your timely response! ♥

Answer (score 0):

Just pasting the code into DrRacket and pressing CTRL+i and I get this:

```
(define (add-into new p lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         (cons new lst)
         ((eq? p 0)
          (cons new lst)
          (else 
           (cons (car lst) (add-into (- p 1) new (cdr l))))))))
```

Notice that you only have one term. If `(null? lst)` is `#f` there are no more terms in the `cond` so it will evaluate to a implementation defined value as it is it is undefined in the specification. In `#lang racket` that value is the same as returned if you evaluate `(void)`

To fix it you need to close the terms in the `cond` so that you have 3 terms instead of one. You should have seen this when you press enter that the parentheses didn't align to the previous term. If you want to use another editor you should get one that aligns and indent lisp syntax as writing lisp without is slightly painful.

Comment: Thank you! I am using an editor through my school, and it hardly gives any feedback and does not align at all. It has been the bane of my existence. In the process now of downloading a new editor :)

Comment: @J.Doe Since you tagged racket you might want to give [DrRacket](https://download.racket-lang.org/) a go?